# How to avoid a circular loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I think I'm being dense here because I keep getting a `stack too deep` error...

I have a `Child` and a `Parent` relational objects. I want 2 things to happen:

- if you try to update the `Child`,  you cannot update its `status_id` to `1` unless it has a `Parent` association
- if you create a `Parent` and then attach it to the `Child`, then the `Child`'s status should be auto-set to `1`.

Here's how the `Parent` association gets added:

```
parent = Parent.new
if parent.save
  child.update_attributes(parent_id:1)
end
```

I have these callbacks on the `Child` model:

```
  validate :mark_complete
  after_update :set_complete

  # this callback is here because there is a way to update the Child model attributes
  def mark_complete
    if self.status_id == 1 && self.parent.blank?
      errors[:base] << ""
    end
  end

  def set_complete
    if self.logistic.present?
      self.update_attribute(:status_id, 1)
    end
  end
```

The code above is actually not that efficient because it's 2 db hits when ideally it would be 1, done all at once. But I find it too brain draining to figure out why... I'm not sure why it's not even working, and therefore can't even begin to think about making this a singular db transaction.

**EXAMPLE**

Hopefully this helps clarify. Imagine a `Charge` model and an `Item` model. Each `Item` has a `Charge`. The `Item` also has an attribute `paid`. Two things:

- If you update the `Item`, you cannot update the `paid` to `true` until the `Item` has been associated with a `Charge` object
- If you link a `Charge` object to a `Item` by updating the `charge_id` attribute on the `Item`, then code should save you time and auto set the `paid` as `true`

Comment: Why don't you just loop the child until the parent ends?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that I find confusing here, but it seems to me that you call `:set_complete` after_update and within `set_complete` you are updating attributes, thus you seem to have a perpetual loop there.  There might be other loops that I can't see but that one stands out to me.

Comment: how would you rewrite it? i can't seem to think of something that works...

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to rewrite it because I'm not 100% sure what you're really trying to do.  I personally would need to see more code to understand the underlying purpose / need of all this.  I'm still confused by the fixed parent_id above.

Comment: the `parent_id` update is just so that the child gets associated with it. an example would be a `Charge` model and an `Item` model, with `paid` being the attribute in question. You can't mark an `Item` as having been `paid` for until it's been associated with a `Charge` object. However, once the `Charge` object is there, you might as well save some time and automatically mark the `Item` as having been `paid`

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid a circularly recursive situation like this is to provide a *flag*  as a parameter (or otherwise) that will stop the loop from continuing.

In this case, (though I am not sure about the case entirely) I think you could provide a flag indicating the origin of the call. If the origin of the update is a charge being attached, then pass a flag that will stop the check from happening or modify it to keep the loop from happening. Perhaps a secondary set of logic is in order for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a `stack level too deep` problem some time back when working with ActiveRecord callbacks. 
In my case the problem was with `update_attribute` after the update goes through the callback i.e. `set_complete` in your case is called again in which the `update_attribute` is triggered again in turn and this repeats endlessly.

I got around that by using `update_column` instead which does not trigger any callbacks or validations however setting a flag is what was advised more often online.

At this point I do not have an answer for reducing your database write operations, and will add to this answer if I can think of anything.

Hope this helps